# How do I restrict an input to be to the second decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm taking an intro to Python and I'm asked to request an input of dimes and quarters and then add the values, I'm trying to restrict either the input to a second decimal for the dimes.

```
dimes = input('How many dimes do you have?: ')
dimes = round(dimes, 2)
```

It's supposed to take an input and put it to the second decimal:

```
input = 5
output = 0.05
```

What it's doing:

```
   dimes = round(dimes, 2)
TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of what this code is supposed to do that it currently isn't doing?

Comment: What does "rn" mean?

Comment: @mkrieger1 ["rn" means "right now"](https://www.cyberdefinitions.com/definitions/RN.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to convert the input to an integer and divide it by 100.

```
dimes = int(input('How many dimes do you have?: ')) / 100
```

This will fail if the user enters something that is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def two_dec(num):
    string = str(num)
    string = string.split('.')
    two_decimal = string[0] + '.' + string[1][:2]
    return float(two_decimal)

print(two_dec(3.999))
print(two_dec(1.0110))
"""
3.99
1.01
"""
```

Just truncate the extra parameters and tell this before hand while taking user input.

After edit of question:

```
dimes = int(input("Enter dimes: "))
print( dimes*0.01 )

"""
dimes = 5 (entered)
output = 0.05
"""
```

Comment: what does truncate mean ?

Comment: Droping any value after two decimal place, Different than round off 
3.999 -> 4 (in round off)
3.999 -> 3.99 (in truncate)

Comment: Don't forget to accept this solution as answer and upvote the solution. If it help.